# Android Studio - Java - Error while evaluating a String

Tags: java, android-studio

this is my code:

```
public String TakeText;
...


TakeText = startBox.getText().toString();
if (marker == null && TakeText == Text1) 
{...}
```

Android Studio debug tool shows me that **TakeText="WoW"** and **Text1="WoW"** and at the same time that **TakeText == Text1** is false.

Why?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: read about how to compare Strings in java :)

Comment: this may helps you: use  if(marker == null && TakeText.equals(Text1)) instead of if(marker == null && TakeText == Text1)

Comment: it works! thanks a lot Mohan